# Centermounted kickstand on touring cyclocross

Tags: touring, cyclocross, kickstand

I just got a new bicycle (cyclocross meant for touring) and a center-mounted kickstand (Pletscher Twin), but it seems it won't fit with the standard mounts. Is this a common issue, and do I have to make a custom fitting to get around it?

This is how they want me to mount:

[image]

But this is what my bicycle looks like (too tight for the standard mount):

[image]

**Update:** Inspired by Batmans suggestions I ended up going for an Upstand: http://upstandingbicycle.com/about-us/

Comment: A cyclocross bike is is typically not going to be designed to hold a kick stand.  Weight, clearance, and collect mud.

Comment: It's not a nice centre stand like you've got, but there are some really solid kickstands that attach to the left chainstay by clamps - on steel or alloy that may be an option.

Comment: Thats an interesting stand design, but I don't know how it will cope on a loaded touring bike versus the Click-Stand (which clearly does work on a loaded touring bike). Another thing to note is that a bike leaned against the ground can't fall over (and in many places, a tree or something can substitute for having a kickstand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't get a safe mount for that type of kickstand on that bike (and likely not any kickstand - the space is just too small). In general, kickstands on good new frames (even touring frames like the Surly LHT) are tricky since they stress the frame in ways the manufacturer did not intend. See [this page from Surly](http://surlybikes.com/info_hole/spew/kickstands_on_long_haul_truckers), for example.

You may want to try a kickstand which doesn't attach to the bike, such as the [Click-Stand](http://www.click-stand.com/).

Comment: That is so surly and I mean it as a noun and a verb.

Answer (score 1):

A touring bike and a cyclosross are similar but this is where you going to find a differences.

A cyclocross bike is is not going to be designed to hold a kick stand. Weight, clearance, and collect mud.

They are going to open that space up between the tire and cross bar to avoid problems with mud.